# Partition function in Quick sort by swapping nodes in Doubly linked list (Java)

Tags: java

I tried to write the code for Quick Sort using doubly linked list in java. I don't know why my partition function is going into infinite loop. Here is my code. I tried to do the partitioning procedure by swapping the nodes (not the data) of the doubly linked list.

```
Node partition(Node left, Node right){

        Node i = left.prev;
        Node pivot = right;
        Node j = left;
        while(j!= right){
            if(j.value<=pivot.value){
                i = i.next;
                //swap(i,j)
                Node prevI = i.prev;
                Node prevJ = j.prev;
                Node nextI = i.next;
                Node nextJ = j.next;

                prevI.next = j;
                j.prev = prevI;
                j.next = nextI;

                prevJ.next = i;
                i.prev = prevJ;
                i.next = nextJ;


            }

            j = j.next;

        }

        // i+1 th node is the correct place for the pivot. so swap pivot and (i+1)th node

        if(i==null){
            i = left;
        }
        else{
            i = i.next;
        }
        Node iPrev = i.prev;
        Node pivotNext = pivot.next;
        Node pivotStore = pivot;
        Node pivotPrev = pivot.prev;

        pivot = i;
        pivot.next = i.next;
        pivot.prev = i.prev;
        left.prev = pivot;

        i = pivotStore;
        pivotPrev.next = i;
        i.prev = pivotPrev;
        i.next = pivotNext;

    return i;

    }
```

Can someone help me!

Comment: Before you set i to i.next, I think you have to check if it is null already

Comment: Yes now I added the null conditions, then also it's going to infinite loop

Comment: `
   while(j!=right){
    if(j.value<pivot.value){
     if(i!=null){
      i = i.next;
      }
     else   {
      i = left;
      } 
     //swap(i,j)
     if(i.value!=left.value){
      Node prevI = i.prev;
      Node prevJ = j.prev;
      Node nextI = i.next;
      Node nextJ = j.next;

      prevI.next = j;
      j.prev = prevI;
      j.next = nextI;

      prevJ.next = i;
      i.prev = prevJ;
      i.next = nextJ;
     }

            }
    
           j = j.next;
                  }
   ` This is the code that I changed inside while loop

Answer (score 0):

try editing 
i = i.next;
(just above //swap(i,j))

with
if(i==null){ i = left; } else { i = i.next; }

this should work.